# Using jQuery and standard JavaScript together

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have this line of JavaScript / jQuery that I'm attempting to use to append an element to the DOM and then attach an `eventlistener` to.

```
$('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).addEventListener("click", function () {toggle(this)}, false);
```

I know the appending part works perfectly but adding an event listener is giving me grief.

Is it possible / advisable to use jQuery and normal JavaScript together like this?
Or is there something in jQuery that would work better. (Very new to jQuery so bear with me).

Comment: jQuery and Javascript are incompatible. jQuery can't take it... (I'm just kidding)

Comment: if you are creating dynamic elements, use http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ to apply the event listener

Comment: To which node should the click handler be bound?

Comment: @Felix - I'm assuming he's attempting to bind it to the inserted element, hence my relocation of the listener in my response.

Comment: @all Sorry, yes I intend to bind to the inserted element

Comment: What is `finalRender` actually? You could avoid binding the event handler to it by binding the event handler to a common parent element.

Comment: Oh and have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials to get you started with jQuery :)

Comment: finalRender is a p tag with a link in it. As nodes not string.

Comment: But... why? A big part of jQuery is to help you bind events in a cross-browser fashion.

Comment: Well I decided to start using Jquery halfway though this little adventure so its all up in the air.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the native methods, then you need to call them against DOM elements, not jQuery objects

```
var clone = finalRender.cloneNode(true);
clone.addEventListener("click", function () {toggle(this)}, false);

$('.faq_answer')
      .prev()
      .append( clone );
```

If you want to use jQuery, then you need to wrap the DOM elements in a jQuery object.

```
  // Drop your DOM element----v----into a jQuery object
var clone = $( finalRender.cloneNode(true) ).bind("click", function (){
    toggle(this);
});

$('.faq_answer')
      .prev()
      .append( clone );
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
 $('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).click(function () {toggle(this)});
```

which is pure jquery

Answer (score 0):

I think you're wanting to add your event Listener to the cloned Node - not to the `prev()` of `.faq_answer`.

If you're importing jQuery, why not use the `.click()` method anyway instead of mixing? It's simpler! :)

```
$('.faq_answer').prev().append(finalRender.cloneNode(true).click(function(){
    toggle(this)
}));
```

Comment: You're trying to call a jQuery method against a DOM element. That won't work.

Comment: What if you wrap it in jquery goodness like `$(finalRender.cloneNode(true)).click(... etc` ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to use them "together" because jQuery **is** JavaScript.  However in this case there's really no reason to bind event handlers directly like that if you are using the library.  It already knows how to manage event handlers, and doing it outside of its control is probably not a good idea unless you *really* know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

I find questions like this are strange, because jQuery is JavaScript.

Based on this mixing up the code that is just plain JavaScript with jQuery code is fine.

But if there is a simpler way of doing what you want in jQuery then I would say to just use jQuery alone.